# Cursor returns zero even when there is data in the database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**DBAdapter.java**

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_FIRSTNAME
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MIDDLENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MAIL_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONFIRM
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH
                            + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
                            + ");");

        public long insertRecord(String firstname, String middlename,
                    String lastname, String username, String mail_id, String pass_word,
                    String re_password, String d_o_b) {

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
                cv.put(KEY_MIDDLENAME, middlename);
                cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lastname);
                cv.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                cv.put(KEY_MAIL_ID, mail_id);
                cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass_word);
                cv.put(KEY_CONFIRM, re_password);
                cv.put(KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH, d_o_b);
                //cv.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
                return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

            }

        public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,KEY_USERNAME+" =?",new String[]{userName},null,null,null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
            return "NOT EXIST";
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
        return password;

    }
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
            dbadapter = new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                            dbadapter.open();
                            String stored_password = dbadapter.getSinlgeEntry(username);
                            Log.i("MainActivity", "The stored password is" + stored_password);
                            if(password.equals(stored_password))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It is logging in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile_view.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Either username or password in invalid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**Logcat :**

```
        12-06 16:58:14.981: I/RegistrationPage(4527): It has reached onclick
        12-06 16:58:14.981: I/RegistrationPage(4527): It has reached the database
        12-06 16:58:15.582: I/RegistrationPage(4527): The records are inserted and it is past insertRecord
        12-06 16:58:15.594: I/RegistrationPage(4527): Database is closed
        12-06 16:58:31.571: I/MainActivity(4527): The stored password isNOT EXIST
        12-06 16:58:31.671: I/MainActivity(4527): Database is opened
        12-06 17:09:31.023: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4527): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
        12-06 17:09:39.931: D/dalvikvm(4527): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1693K, 9% free 20048K/21959K, paused 13ms+20ms
```

---

EDIT : 
I am unable to match the username and password. The method `getSingleentry` is supposed to return the password but it always returns NOT EXIST though there are entries in the database, the cursor always returns NOT EXIST as if there is no data in the database.

Can someone please help me with this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method,

```
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
        Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,KEY_USERNAME+"='" + username +"'",null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = "";
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        { 
             password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
        } 
       return password;
    }
```

Comment: Am trying it now. Will let ya know. Thanks for your time and effort. Appreciated.

Comment: Well done,You did it Mr.Genius. Lots of thanks to ya. Keep flowing it mate. Thanks again.

Comment: This will break when the user name contains quotes. There is no reason to remove the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use like this by using POJO Objects:

```
public List<UserPojo> getNameList() {
        List<UserPojo> contactList = new ArrayList<UserPojo>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Class_Levels";

        open();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserPojo names = new UserPojo();
                names.setC_Id(cursor.getString(0));
                names.setC_Name(cursor.getString(1));

                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(names);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        close();
        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

This is Just a Sample You can achieve your requirements like this way just try it.

Comment: Thanks pal. Tried it but its a bit confusing and am already questioning myself a lot so am gonna skip it. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: Never give up bro try it you will achieve sure.

Comment: Comments like these help me a lot. Hats off Mr.Nagaraja. Keep that attitude up mate.